# Discrete Math - Quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Describe using quantifiers:

1. $x\in\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k$
2. $x\in\bigcap_{k=1}^nA_k$

My work: $i=\{1,2,3,\dots, n\}$

1. $(\exists x),(x\in A_i)$
2. $(\forall x),(x\in A_i)$

> What I need help is explaining with words. Currently I have:

- a) There exists $i$ for every $x\in A_i$
- b) There always is $i$ for every $x$ in $A_i$

Comment: I believe your first "A" in part b of your work should be flipped over ;-) I assume you meant "for all"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answer is not  correct. It should be, given $I:=\{1,2,\dots, n\}$,

1. $\exists k\in I, x\in A_k$
2. $\forall k\in I, x\in A_k$

In words, that is

1. There exists a $1\leq k\leq n$ such that $x$ is in $A_k$
2. For all $1\leq k\leq n$, $x$ is in $A_k$